# How to display only directories from a file?

Tags: text-processing

Hello i have a text file which contains data like below

```
/nrt/www/html/USA/anil.php
/nrt/www/html/USA/anil1.php
/nrt/www/html/USA/anil2.php
```

can any one tell me how to display only directories from text file.

i need output like this

```
/nrt/www/html/USA
/nrt/www/html/USA
/nrt/www/html/USA
```

Comment: could you please add a sample of needed outputs?

Comment: Something like `/nrt/www/html/USA/` ?

Answer (score 2):

With bash, you could use :
`dirname $(cat <file>)`

Answer (score 0):

You could split the list and execute dirname like

```
LST="/nrt/www/html/USA/anil.php
/nrt/www/html/USA/anil1.php
/nrt/www/html/USA/anil2.php"
for fic in $(echo $LST) ; do
  echo $(dirname $fic)
done
```

Assuming your file is named "glop.lst" code would be :

```
for fic in $(cat glop.lst) ; do
  DIR=$(dirname $fic)
  echo $DIR
  #...do something with it :)
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the file through `sed`

```
sed 's!/[^/]*$!!' textfile
```

If you're already processing the data line by line in a `bash` script you could use its built-in operators to strip the trailing element

```
item='/nrt/www/html/USA/anil.php'
dir="${item%/*}"
```